# MVVM, ObservableCollection, async, etc

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8, mvvm

So, I'm on to the next phase of my education and have reached a bit of a blocker related to my use of SQLite (this is for a universal app, with my current focus being on the Windows Phone side of that solution). My question is somewhat independent of SQLite but I will use it as an example.

I am looking at SQLite as the database for my app (based on various suggestions and comments here and elsewhere). Specifically, I am designing my view -> viewmodel -> model and I'm not sure of an appropriate pattern for passing around ObservableCollection.

Let me start at the model. I am making a call to SQLite-net's QueryAsync() method. So, buried deep in the model I have any await on the call to QueryAsync(). The method in which that lives (let's call it GetData(), for simplicity) is marked with async. So, that's the model.

Up at the view level I need to bind to a property of the viewmodel. Let's call that property GetDataVM(). Since it's a property I use a getter - and, as far as I can tell, I can't use await in getters. Is that true? Given the asynchronous call in the model - QueryAsync() - it seems I need an await, right?

I am **sure** I have some basic assumptions wrong here. But the basic principle I am trying to understand is what a control in my view must bind to when that property calls a method in the model that includes an async method.

I'm not finding this particularly easy to explain :) But, stepping right back, what I want is very simple, conceptually. I want a control to bind to a viewmodel property that, in turn, retrieves data from the model, which retrieves data from SQLite.

And I'm confused :)

Any help would be most appreciated (probably starting with clarifying questions about what the heck I'm trying to achieve :)).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have an [MSDN article on this topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx).

The gist of it is this: as others have noted, a property read should be an immediate operation, whereas an asynchronous operation is (generally speaking) not immediate.

So, what you first need to do is decide what your UI will look like *while* the data is loading. When your VM loads, it should initialize its data in that "loading" state, and when the data arrives, the VM should *update* to the "ready" state (or to an "error" state if the operation failed).

In my MSDN article, I introduce a `NotifyTaskCompletion<T>` type that is pretty much just a data-binding-friendly wrapper around `Task<T>`. This allows you to do the state transitions via XAML bindings.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, getters are not async. I would also refrain from trying a hack to make them work that way.

It is considered bad practise to have long running getters and good practise to wrap long running processes as await able asyncs.

You can see why the two are not compatible.

Instead, is it possible to trigger your async call from a command? That way you can make the call async and just assign the result to the property via the setter, that should call INotifyPropertyChanged PropertyChanged event to update your UI.

Comment: Thank you. I haven't got to Commands yet :) But, before I do, one thing I should clarify is that, since my dataset is small, my objective in the code I am writing right now was merely to pre-populate the model with data persisted in SQLlite. I had assumed that this retrieval (through QueryAsync) would belong in the model but the previous response suggests that is a poor assumption on my part and the viewmodel should retrieve that data (and populate the model). But, at the most basic level, all I am really trying to do is retrieve data from SQLite and QueryAsync is an async call.

Comment: You're viewmodel is where the trigger to load the data should sit, your model is the provider of that data. Thanks for clarification, you might then look at handing off the loading of data to the constructor. That also can not be async but if you wrap the call in an async void method (can be frowned upon) you can call that.

Answer (score 0):

In general it is the ViewModel's responsibility to load the model (of course it could pass this responsibility to a repository class)

This way the ViewModel can contain the awaits and the Model can consist of plain data containing classes.

The View and ViewModel decide when to sync the model to and from the data source.

The role of the ViewModel is to mediate between the Model and the View. Most of the times I do not design the Model but accept it as a given from the data source and in many cases the Model is generated from a contract by a tool (Entity Framework, Web Services, ...) So I treat the Model as a dumb data container that changes when the data source changes.

The design of the View is driven by the user (requirements) so I am not in control of that either.

The ViewModel is where I get to design and code the transition between View and Model so that is also where I decide (based on user and technical requirements) when and how to load the data (Model) and transform it to match the structure needed by the View.

Many times the actual connecting to the data source is coded in a repository class so the ViewModel is not aware of the actual data source (connection/technology) This way it is easier to connect to another data source to support unit testing or the actual migration to another data source.

Try to put **one** responsibility in each class/layer.

Comment: Thank you. That is something I missed along the way and I appreciate your the clarification. I had assumed that the model was the "persistence" layer and would be responsible for the loading aspect (from the persistent store, in my case SQLite). So, I had assumed that the call to QueryAsync would therefore belong in the model (not the viewmodel) and then expose that for the viewmodel to "consume". It seems you are saying that the interaction with SQLite belongs in the ViewModel, which has the role of creating instances in the model? Or have I totally missed that again? :) Thank you.

Comment: @MarkWilliams I added to my answer