# Role of the model in a "traditional" C# / SQLite MVVM app

Tags: c#, sqlite, mvvm, viewmodel

Based on a response in [a separate thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25499037/mvvm-observablecollection-async-etc), I'm concerned that I have missed a basic principle of MVVM as I learn this stuff. I get the easier stuff about the view binding to the view model, notifications, etc. The underlying technical aspects make sense to me. What is less clear is where the boundaries exist between the viewmodel and the model.

I am trying to build a universal all (with my focus right now being on the Windows Phone part). I will use SQLite to persist and retrieve data. And that simple aspect is where I am not clear.

I had assumed that classes I write will form the "model" and those classes would be responsible for retrieving data from SQLite. The viewmodel would bind to properties on the model classes and the view would bind to properties in the view. As part of all this, it was my assumption that all the interaction with SQLite would be in my model.

Now, based on a comment in a separate thread, I fear I have that wrong. The statement was that the viewmodel would be responsible for "loading" the model. It - not the model - would presumably interact directly with SQLite.

Well, that threw a spanner in my understanding and now I wonder if I missed the wood through the trees all along :) In my simple app what is the model layer? Can SQLite itself be considered the model, with the viewmodel interacting directly with SQLite. If so, what's the role of model classes I might write - if my needs are simple (CRUD into SQLite), so I NEED classes at the model layer?

While I know there's no one "right" way to design such an app, I want to make sure I follow basic, accepted principles. With that in mind, in a "simple" MVVM / SQLite app, what is exactly IS the model later?

Thanks

Comment: Could you update the question with a link to the thread you mention?

Comment: @venerik - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25499037/mvvm-observablecollection-async-etc

Answer (score 0):

In general, the model is the set of classes that contains the data as it enters the client. It could be a Entity Framework model or a classic DataSet or RecordSet. It could even be a string containing JSON (or another format).

In general I accept the Model to be dictated by the data source. I use it as it is and when it changes due to changes in the data source (normalisation, change of protocol, new version) I adjust the transformation from the Model to ViewModel in the ViewModel.

So a change in the Data Source will only affect the Model and the transformation logic in the ViewModel. The ViewModel's interface and the View should be as stable as possible because these should be driven by user requirements. Unless of course the changes in the Model are to provide new functionality in the Views as well, in which case the ViewModel and View need to change to show the new data.

Comment: Thank you again, Erno. That makes sense. I am trying to strike a balance between a good "theoretical" design across the view, viewmodel and model vs. a practical approach that allows me to develop my app quickly and efficiently, while also allowing me to make changes in a logical fashion in the future. One factor that is important here is that I am trying to build a very (very!) simple app. It's not "enterprise" app that will scale, accommodate all sorts of deployment and design change and so on. It's merely a Windows Phone app with a local database (SQLite).

Comment: My objective, therefore is to use MVVM while being pragmatic about the theory around isolation of concerns, etc. With that in mind, a more specific question. For a simple app that accesses all it's data in a local SQLite instance, is it reasonable to consider SQLite as the model - namely, the viewmodel creates the database (through the SQLite API), queries data through QueryAsync(), etc. Put another way, do I REALLY need a set of classes in the model layer that sit between the viewmodel and SQLite?

Comment: With SQLite being "the model", I still get to have a stable "contract" between the view and viewmodel (the viewmodel handling transformations, etc).

Comment: I would consider SQLite the data source, not the model. The odel would be whatever data structure I get from the API that I use to retrieve the data from SQLite. Do not worry too much about it. Nobody is going to force you to NEED anything. MVVM is just a pattern. Use it as needed. Having Model classes could allow you to switch more easily between data sources e.g., to unit test.

Comment: Thank you again, Erno. This has been an interesting (and, frankly, fun) investigation for me, as I try to find the balance. Consistent with your implication to not be held hostage by the "purity" of MVVM, I've decided to not go with an obvious model layer. Bearing in mind that this isn't an enterprise app (or even a particularly sophisticated one) I'm having the viewmodel interact directly with SQLite. I understand the conceptual inconsistencies with that but I found myself replicating (for example) "Item" representations in the viewmodel and the model classes.

Comment: That got a bit tedious every time I wanted to add a new field, etc. I've still got a good division between the view and the viewmodel and that buys me some MVVM benefits, for a simple app like mine, this approach seems like a good middle ground. Thanks again.